# compare background color of layout in android application

Tags: android

I want to make an if statement in which I will compare the color of my layout background color, something like this:

```
 RelativeLayout screen = (RelativeLayout) findViewById (R.id.screen);
 if(screen.getBackgroundColor() == "#FFFFFFFF"){
    //do something...
 }
 else{
   //do something else...
 }
```

I can't find out how to get the background color. I am setting the color by: `screen.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no direct `getBackgroundColor()`, but if you really need to know the color value, you should retrieve view's [Paint object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) and get color from it:

```
Paint viewPaint = ((PaintDrawable) view.getBackground()).getPaint();
int colorARGB = viewPaint.getColor();
```

Note this contains alpha as well, so be careful with your comparison (or get rid of alpha if you just need to compare RGB:

```
int colorRGB = colorARGB & 0x00ffffff;
```

This will work on all API levels.

**EDIT**

As for the comparision - once you got color retrieved you can use [Color.parseColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor%28java.lang.String%29) and compare the result usual way:

```
if( colorRGB == Color.parseColor("#ffffff") ) {
   // matches...
}
```

or same with ARGB:

```
if( colorARGB == Color.parseColor("#ffffffff") ) {
   // matches...
}
```

And if you are doing this frequently (like in. list adapter) I'd parse it once and store the results for reuse.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a compare? I didn't understand what would I have in colorARGB ("#000000" or "000000" or something completely different). Thanks

Comment: How can you cast ColorDrawable to PaintDrawable?

Answer (score 2):

In can you use API level 11+, you can cast the `screen.getBackground()` into a `ColorDrawable` and then call the method `getColor()`. Unfortunately this method is not available for API level < 11.

Hope this helps!